# Add text to specialized Index

Tags: indexing

I am writing a large book consisting of a base document and included chapters and have defined a special index:

```
\makeindex[name=artists,title=Index of artists,columns=2]
```

I would like to add some fixed text on the first page of *only this special index* (not the regular Index), under its title, of the form

```
Page numbers in bold refer to blahblahblah...
```

I've tried simply adding this text to the base book document before or after the \makeindex... command, but this doesn't work.  (Nor did I really expect it to.)

How do I add such a line to a specialized index, under its title?

---

Thanks to @Ivan's answer below, I figured out how to place such a note in *only* one of the indexes:  place the special text line

```
\setindexprenote{Page numbers in bold refer to blahblahblah...}
```

before printing the associated index, but afterwards "clear" it by putting in new "empty" text,

```
\setindexprenote{ }
```

or better

```
\noindexprenote
```

that gets set in other indexes.

Comment: With the updated answer below you do not need `\setindexprenote{ }` anymore as `\indexprologue` only affects the next `\printindex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

The first solution should be to use `\indexprologue{...}` just before the index that requires a prenote:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
  \makeindex[name=artists,title=Index of artists,columns=2]
  \makeindex[name=locations,title=Index of locations,columns=2]

\begin{document}
 
Hello World\index[artists]{World, Hello}

St. Anford\index[locations]{St. Anford}

\indexprologue{Page numbers in bold refer to blahblahblah...}
\printindex[artists]
\printindex[locations]

\end{document}
```

You can achieve the same result through `idxlayout` and the `\setindexprenote` command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[totoc,columns=1]{idxlayout}
  \makeindex[name=artists,title=Index of artists,columns=2]
  \makeindex[name=locations,title=Index of locations,columns=2]

\begin{document}
 
Hello World\index[artists]{World, Hello}

St. Anford\index[locations]{St. Anford}

\setindexprenote{Page numbers in bold refer to blahblahblah...}
\printindex[artists]
\noindexprenote
\printindex[locations]

\end{document}
```

In this case you can limit the prenote to a particular index also by enclosing it in a group:

```
\begingroup
\setindexprenote{Page numbers in bold refer to blahblahblah...}
\printindex[artists]
\endgroup
\printindex[locations]
```

Comment: Almost... almost.  I need to place this added text line on *only* the special index (***Index of artists***) but *not* the regular ***Index***.  Alas, your solution puts it on both.  How do I limit it to just one of the several indexes?

Comment: According to the `idxlayout` documentation: "With multiple indexes, use the command \noindexprenote to reset the prenote
text to empty and to take care of the proper spacing between index heading and
first entry.". I will update the answer.